# Setting breakpoints in .class files Intellij

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I'm trying to debug the code mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595692/java-keystore-fails-to-store-certificate-chains) question, more specifically, the last line in the following code:

```
        // client credentials
        KeyStore keyStore = null;

        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setKeyEntry(CryptographyUtils.CLIENT_NAME, endCredential.getPrivateKey(), CryptographyUtils.CLIENT_PASSWORD,
                new Certificate[]{endCredential.getCertificate(), interCredential.getCertificate(), rootCredential.getCertificate()});
        keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream(CryptographyUtils.CLIENT_NAME + ".p12"), CryptographyUtils.CLIENT_PASSWORD);
```

Going to the declaration of **.store()** (using Ctrl + B) opens a file **KeyStore.java**:

```
public final void store(OutputStream stream, char[] password)
        throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            CertificateException
    {
        if (!initialized) {
            throw new KeyStoreException("Uninitialized keystore");
        }
        keyStoreSpi.engineStore(stream, password);
    }
```

The last call **.engineStore()** actually writes the certificates to an output stream. Going to the implementation of the method (Ctrl + Alt + B) the following options are shown:

[image: store keys]

The package imported containing the method in my code is from:

```
import java.security.KeyStore;
```

I have put a breakpoint in **KeyStore.java** and it is reached. However, breakpoints placed in decompiled .class files such as those shown in the picture are not.

How may I debug the **.engineStore()** method?

Comment: Of course, not what you are looking for: but if the point is to debug a certain method; and breakpoints within that method dont work; why not put a breakpoint on the line that invokes the method; and then do some "step into"?

Comment: I tried stepping into as well as force stepping into. A lot of the classes are implementing containers such as vectors and lists which you are inevitably stepping into. It is easy "to get lost" in the code and loose sight of the scope at which you are debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You need to attach `source files` if you want to debug that.You cant debug `.class` files.

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485173/how-to-step-into-code-from-jars-non-jdk-using-intellij) to understand how you can add source code to the library configuration.

Comment: And how may I do that?

Comment: Download source of that jar and add.

Comment: The suggested question is dated. In intellij 14 I cannot see the add sources button as mentioned in the post.

Comment: Which is intellij version of yours?

Comment: I am using Intellij 14

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94541/discussion-between-prince-mani-gupta-and-sebi).

Comment: I think the author of the question wanted to know how to see how to debug the code that runs inside the connected library without open-source code.

I am also interested in this question until I found the answer.